# Is there a way to render a webpage into a shrinked like control panel like?

Tags: html-rendering, shrink, custom-dimensions

I'm new to web development and not sure how to explain this, I'm building a tool with lots of links and features to help making things at a call center easier but I wish everytime the page is opened it resizes to a small rectangular version. Is there a way this can be done? Thanks!![image]

Comment: Is it possible to add an illustration to clarify your needs? Do you want to change the size of the browser window?

Comment: hey Jonny i uploaded a picture of what i want to do. I know i can use bootstrap but i once saw someonw doing so.ethung similar and it looked like the original version was rendered in a high smaller resolution somehow.